# Slow Matlab R2018b TypedArray array access in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

I am using MATLAB R2018b mex functions to integrate a C++ library with my MATLAB code. As part of that, I need to take data in a MATLAB array and save into a C++ pointer array and a C++ vector of structures. However, mapping the matlab typed array is proving to be very slow (~0.4 seconds for ~800,000 elements).

here is the relevant code

```
const matlab::data::TypedArray<float> Vertices = std::move(inputs[0]); 
float* positions = new float[Vertices.getNumberofElements()];
for (size_t i = 0; i < Vertices.getDimensions()[0]; i ++)
{
    ctr = 9 * i;
    positions[ctr + 0] = Vertices[i][0];
    positions[ctr + 1] = Vertices[i][1];
    positions[ctr + 2] = Vertices[i][2]; 
}
```

What is causing this loop to be slow? I tried re-ordering array access for Vertices to try and make the code more cache friendly, but that didn't produce a meaningful speed-up. Right now, the loop is ~0.4ms for 800,000 elements, ideally memory copy should take far less time, right?

When I looked over previous advice, I found that most answers use older mex functions, where the new(?) MATLAB C++ API doesn't have the same functions or structure.

Edit:

I followed Cris' advice and used a loop over iterators, that increased speed by about half, to 0.14 seconds.

The new code I'm using is:

```
    const matlab::data::TypedArray<float> Vertices = std::move(inputs[0]); 
    float* positions = new float[Vertices.getNumberofElements()];
for (auto it = Vertices.begin(); it != Vertices.end(); ++it)
{
    positions[ctr] = *it; 
    ++ctr; 
}
```

So it is faster, but still surprisingly slow (0.14 seconds for 800,000 elements). Is there any other way to speed this loop?

Comment: Matlab stores data in Column-Major order. C++ expects Row-Major. This code may be exhibiting very poor cache behaviour as a result. Nevermind. You tried that already.

Comment: Try using an iterator: `auto it = Vertices.begin(); *it; ++it;` etc. That should be much more efficient than the `[]` operator, which likely is checking bounds and so forth. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.typedarray.html#d120e11864 and here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.typediterator.html

Comment: I tried using iterators and got a speedup, but still surprisingly slow.

Comment: You can avoid the copy altogether, by passing `&*Vertices.begin()` to your C++ function. If I got it right, that should be a `float const*`. If you need it to be writable, use a non-const `TypedArray` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 4):

I got a major speedup by applying Cris advice and using the following code:

```
const matlab::data::TypedArray<float> Vertices = std::move(inputs[0]);
float* positions = new float[Vertices.getNumberofElements()];
memcpy(positions,&*Vertices.begin,sizeof(float)*Vertices.getNumberofElements());
```

Runtime went from 0.14 (using standard Visual Studio optimization) to 0.0035, which is acceptably fast for my application.